# Get the file/image name from the URL which does not end with a file name and extension

Tags: android, android-webview, android-download-manager

My query is almost similar to one asked in the following link :
[How to get file name when clicking on URL in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879119/how-to-get-file-name-when-clicking-on-url-in-webview) 
 I don't want to use **URLUtil** for the reasons mentioned there. 
Also, getting the file name using **Content-Disposition** header field does not work in my case.
 I am using Android DownloadManager API for downloading file/images. I have to set destination filename using **setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (String dirType, String subPath)** method. 
 I have observed that DownloadManager provide name such as "downloadfile.jpeg", "downloadfile-2.jpeg" when any image url is used. I have looked into the DownloadManager source code and found COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME and COLUMN_TITLE that might be storing the name of file.
 
How can I get the file/image name as done in DownloadManager API ? 
 If not, is there any way I can detect that these urls does not contain filename at the end so that I can provide my custom name ?

Comment: Hi please check this answer hope you'll getting help from this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13322285/760489

Comment: No it won't help me because that solution will provide the file name after the completion of download. Instead I want the file name prior to download so that I can save the file with my custom file name.

Comment: Also, I could not use approaches of URLUtil and Content-Disposition header for getting file name that I have already mentioned in the question.